# VBScript tags get red squigglies in ascx file but render fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, vbscript

I apologize in advance if this is clear as mud. I'm new to Visual Studio, ASP.net, C# *and* VBScript.

The problem: validation errors on a .ascx file, on legit code which renders just fine on the site.
The other problem: not all VBScript gets flagged as an error - the stuff in quotes, like this, doesn't get the red squiggle:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%= TemplateSourceDirectory %>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
```

VBScript that is *not* in quotes seems to get interpreted as .NET and therefore gets flagged for bad syntax:

```
<% var userData = UserSessionData.Current; %>
   ~~~ ~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(I manually added the tildes here to indicate what gets flagged.)

Basically anything in <% %> tags is making Visual Studio bark at me. The only solution I've found so far is to turn off the real-time error checking, which isn't a tenable solution, IMHO.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could tell VS to interpret <% %> as VBScript and not .NET stuff?

Comment: you need to put the `var userDate =` outside of the `<%UserSession.Current%>`

Comment: This issue transcends the "var userData" thing. Literally anything in <% %> tags shows up as an error. IF statements, etc. Also, as I said earlier, the code renders fine, which tells me that it's a Visual Studio validation problem.

Comment: wrap single quotes around it like this 
`'<%UserSession.Current%>'`